# Can't boot with second monitor plugged in

Tags: boot, hdmi, 20.04, thinkpad

I have a Thinkpad T580. When I boot with second monitor plugged in, the system doesn't boot and stops with Lenovo's logo. However, I have no problems on 19.10.

For a correct boot, I must plug in second monitor only after login screen.

Is there any way to avoid the inconvenience?

Comment: Was the system stuck on Lenovo logo for ever?

Comment: yes, with ubuntu spinner :\ ; so sad because on previus versions everythings was fine